# How to retain backing of a CAMetalLayer?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, metal

I am unable to find a way to retain backing for a CAMetalLayer, as nextDrawable provides a different MTLTexture each time from a pool. Even if I set the appropriate loadAction and storeAction on the render pass descriptor, backing will not happen. Contents flash as textures are swapped by the nextDrawable call.

I want similar behaviour to kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking in OpenGL ES.

Anyone figured this one out?

Comment: have you tried subclassing MTKView instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nextDrawable will always provide you a texture in an undefined state, and as far as I know there isn't a simple option like kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking to change that behaviour.

However, it is apparently possible to implement a copy by keeping the old drawable around for a little longer and manually performing a GPU copy from the previous texture to the next. https://devforums.apple.com/message/1060027#1060027

You will, however, have to set CAMetalLayer.framebufferOnly to NO, which comes 'at a cost to performance' according to the documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Animation/Reference/CAMetalLayer_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CAMetalLayer/framebufferOnly)

Comment: Since there are only 3 drawables in the pool of a `CAMetalLayer`, holding the drawable around longer than you absolutely need to before presenting it might risk blocking or failing on the next attempt at `nextDrawable`. Might be better to attack it from the other direction, and render to an offscreen texture, which you can hold for as long as you want, and then retrieve the drawable, BLIT (or better yet, render) that texture to the drawable texture, and then present the drawable. That will hold the drawable for a much shorter time, reducing the risk of blocking.

Comment: Yes, I agree that using a render to texture may well be a better alternative. When I have needed to retain the back buffer for a project's loading screen, I used a render-to-texture solution because the approach was more portable than messing around with drawables. I also didn't like the sound of the framebufferOnly performance cost which I think you have to pay for throughout the whole project, not just the specific scenes where you want the backing.

Comment: Hi @BillHollings offscreen texture works great, thanks for the suggestion. Is there any reason why you prefer rendering over BLIT? I am currently rendering to an offscreen texture in one render pass and then using a BLIT encoder to copy over the offscreen texture to the layer's drawable texture. Is it better to replace the BLIT phase with another render phase?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. No reason for preferring rendering over BLIT for your needs. A second render pass is useful if you want to perform further image processing (which is the more general use of off-screen rendering). But BLIT is fine for a pixel-for-pixel copy, and is possibly faster. So perhaps my "better yet" assertion was a bit misdirected in this case.  :^)